# Android VKAPI вернуть полученные данные

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Здравствуйте.
Возник вопрос о том, как можно вернуть данные полученные от VK API Android SDK?
у меня есть функция, которая должна вернуть полученные данные которые вернул `VKResponse` однако когда я делаю `return data`, то функция возвращает пустое значение...

код функции

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUsers(String city, int ofset)
{
    final ArrayList<String> rez = new ArrayList<>();

    VKRequest search_users = new VKRequest("users.search", VKParameters.from("count", 1, "hometown", city, "sex", 1, "status", 6, "offset", ofset, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_max_orig, contacts, last_seen, photo_id"));

    search_users.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            try
            {
                jUsers = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
                userObject = jUsers.getJSONObject("response");
                usersArray = userObject.getJSONArray("items");

                Log.e("VK_FOUND_USERS_ARRAY", String.valueOf(usersArray));

                for (int i = 0; i < usersArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    object = usersArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.e("VK_CONCRETE_USER_OBJECT", String.valueOf(object));


                    rez.add( object.getString("first_name") );
                    rez.add( object.getString("last_name") );
                    rez.add( object.getString("photo_max_orig") );

                    if ( object.has("home_phone") )
                        rez.add( object.getString("home_phone") );
                    if ( object.has("mobile_phone") )
                        rez.add( object.getString("mobile_phone") );
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException je)
            {
                je.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    Log.e("VK_FUNCTION_REZULT", String.valueOf(rez));
    return rez; //возвращает ""
}
```

З.Ы в Java и Android я пока что ещё новичок, так что не судите строго за код и такой вопрос=)

**UPDATE 1**
вот код функции как предложил @rjhdby

```
public static ArrayList<String> getUsers(String city, int ofset)
{
    final ArrayList<String> rez = new ArrayList<>();

    VKRequest search_users = new VKRequest("users.search", VKParameters.from("count", 1, "hometown", city, "sex", 1, "status", 6, "offset", ofset, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_max_orig, contacts, last_seen, photo_id"));

    search_users.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            try
            {
                jUsers = new JSONObject(response.responseString);
                userObject = jUsers.getJSONObject("response");
                usersArray = userObject.getJSONArray("items");

                Log.e("VK_FOUND_USERS_ARRAY", String.valueOf(usersArray));

                for (int i = 0; i < usersArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    object = usersArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.e("VK_CONCRETE_USER_OBJECT", String.valueOf(object));


                    rez.add( object.getString("first_name") );
                    rez.add( object.getString("last_name") );
                    rez.add( object.getString("photo_max_orig") );

                    if ( object.has("home_phone") )
                        rez.add( object.getString("home_phone") );
                    if ( object.has("mobile_phone") )
                        rez.add( object.getString("mobile_phone") );
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException je)
            {
                je.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("VK_FUNCTION_REZULT", String.valueOf(rez));
            return rez; //Error:(403, 24) error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
search_users.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
```

Запускается асинхронно и вызывает `VKRequest.VKRequestListener()` тогда, когда получен ответ.

Соответственно тут у вас `rez` еще пустой, так как листенер еще не отработал.

```
Log.e("VK_FUNCTION_REZULT", String.valueOf(rez));
return rez; //возвращает ""
```

**UPD**

На самом деле это очень плохая идея синхронно ожидать ответ от метода, результат которого зависит от вложенного асинхронного кода.

Есть два пути, один плохой, другой хороший.

1) Плохой. Очень плохой. Даже и не думайте о его использовании, привожу только для понимания того, как это все работает.

```
        catch (JSONException je){
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
while(rez.size() == 0){
    //курим
}
return rez;
```

2) Обычно делается по другому.

Меняем сигнатуру вашего метода следующим образом.

```
public static void getUsers(String city, int ofset)
```

Добавляем еще один метод, который принимает результат и делает то, что вам нужно

```
public static void doSomethingWhenUsersReceived(ArrayList<String> rez){
    //обрабатываем результат
}
```

В теле листенера, когда результат получен, вызываем этот метод

```
            MyClass.doSomethingWhenUsersReceived(rez);
        }
        catch (JSONException je)
        {
```

Comment: мне выбрасывает ошибку `Error:(403, 24) error: incompatible types: unexpected return value`

Comment: @vladimir я вас немного обманул, не со зла. Сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: @vladimir дополнил ответ

Comment: хорошо, а как теперь достать к примеру TextView в функции которая должна обрабатывать принятые данные? P.S извиняюсь за такие простые вопросы, просто раньше с таким не сталкивался и в google что то найти тоже не могу ответ =(

Comment: всё, разобрался =) @rjhdby большое спасибо за помощь!!!!